# How to re-use the same nftables set for both saddr and daddr?

Tags: networking, nftables

I am using the following nftables config to whitelist machines that can use the router:

```
table bridge filter {
    set authorized {
        typeof ether saddr
        flags constant
        elements = {
            aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa,
            ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        }
    }

    set authorized2 {
        typeof ether daddr
        flags constant
        elements = {
            aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa,
            ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        }
    }

    chain input {
            type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;
            ether saddr @authorized accept
            ether daddr @authorized2 accept
    }

}
```

The 2 sets are identical except for the type.

Is there any way to specify and use only 1 set for both `saddr` and `daddr` to avoid repeating the MAC addresses?

Answer (score 2):

That's simple: `typeof ether saddr` is the same type as `typeof ether daddr` as can be checked in the man page for [`nft(8)`](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8#ETHERNET_HEADER_EXPRESSION):

> [ETHERNET HEADER EXPRESSION](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8#ETHERNET_HEADER_EXPRESSION)
>
> ```
> ether {daddr | saddr | type}
> ```
>
> Table 37. Ethernet header expression types
>
> | Keyword | Description | **Type** |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | daddr | Destination MAC address | **ether_addr** |
> | saddr | Source MAC address | **ether_addr** |
> | type | EtherType | ether_type |

That means one can define a single set with one of the 3 equivalent ways below, with the same result. The visual distinction didn't exist before [*nftables* 0.9.4](https://lists.netfilter.org/pipermail/netfilter-announce/2020/000238.html) where the new `typeof` keyword that uses definitions from the 1st column was introduced as an alternative to the `type` keyword that uses definitions from the 3rd column.

- the original `type` keyword (requires to check documentation for the exact type)

  ```
  type ether_addr
  ```
- or the newer `typeof` keyword (can more or less reuse the vocabulary  from a rule using it)

  - either

    ```
    typeof ether saddr
    ```
  - or

    ```
    typeof ether daddr
    ```

So in the end the ruleset can be written just as:

```
table bridge filter {
    set authorized {
        typeof ether saddr
        flags constant
        elements = {
            aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa,
            ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        }
    }

    chain input {
            type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;
            ether saddr @authorized accept
            ether daddr @authorized accept
    }
}
```

Note: the current ruleset accepts anything from the set or anything to the set. It doesn't match *both* at the same time. Also, since it's the *input* hook rather than the *forward* hook, having to accept the destination MAC address being one own's MAC address looks a bit weird (then of course, when obfuscating, one should not set the 1st's byte multicast bit, it's not valid as source. But if the goal is to match a broadcast destination that's one way to do it).

Comment: So, is the 'typeof ether saddr' then ignored when the rule contains ether daddr @authorized, and the rule is matched against the daddr instead (overriding the set definition)?

Comment: typeof ether saddr <=> typeof ether daddr <=> type ether_addr . There's nothing ignored. The set is searched each time for a match.